# Force symbols to resolve when creating shared libarary

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I am creating a shared library (.so), which contains my code, plus some third-party .so's. Specifically, one of the third-party .so's is libaide.so. After linking, when I do a `nm -DC mylib.so`, I see that all symbols from libaide.so are undefined ("U" in nm output). Now, I can resolve them when I create the final executable, by linking with libaide.so at the final compile/link, but I would like to give mylib.so to others, and not require them to add `-laide` to their final linking step. Is this even possible? How do I do this?

Comment: Can you just resolve those symbols in your library ie: provide an implementation, and export it, when the user also provides an implementation and links that library directly, his symbols will override yours.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I guess I'm not clear what you mean when you say "provide an implementation" - Linux linking is not my strong suit here. My code is indeed using some of the libaide.so APIs, which are still currently marked as Undefined by nm.

Comment: you should create a minimal reproducible example of your problem, like 3 cpp files and 2 headers , each one containing a single function in a new question, so that people can understand your problem, i have a few scenarios and solutions in mind but i am not sure which will fit your case .... and you WILL have to rewrite your interfaces in some cases.

Comment: You will have to hide the fact that you depend on the other library from people trying to use your library ... this depends on what exactly do you use from that library and how you expect your interface to look .... so you should create a very simple example of a class or a function that looks like what you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there are two ways.

The first is to use `-Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` for all the intermediate steps, which ignores unresolved symbols in shared libs.

The second is to produce a stub shared library for intermediate steps, which has the same apis as your `mylib.so`, but all the implementations are fake so that the stub does not depend on `libaide.so`. And when running, you should use the real `mylib.so`.

Both ways need `libaide.so` present when running.

Comment: This method would still require `-Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` in the final link step though, correct? This is what I'm trying to avoid. The stub shared library is probably a non-starter, given the very large API set in mylib.so.

Comment: If you just use a few apis from `libaide.so`, maybe you can try dynamic loading (`dlopen` and `dlsym` ...).

Comment: @courage LOL! Your comment caused the O.P. to open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77984833/sigabrt-at-startup-in-debugging-macos-app.